# Rosserial/Arduino Publishers and Subscribers

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have been working with arduino and rosserial, and we were wondering if it is possible to both send and receive information through the arduino so that it can communicate with the computer, instead of only sending information to or receiving information from the computer.

If so, does anyone have an example code we could see to point us in the right direction?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10645/rosserial/arduino-publishers-and-subscribers/) by [UAV](https://answers.ros.org/users/789/uav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [subarashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/49972/subarashi/) on 2020-06-29**:
Is there any way to have the publisher outside the void loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can have many publishers and subscribers at the same time -- the current implementation supports up to 25 of each on the Arduino (you'll probably run out of bandwidth before you hit that though).

The following can be found under ros_lib/examples folder as float64_test.pde:

```
/* 
 * rosserial::std_msgs::Float64 Test
 * Receives a Float64 input, subtracts 1.0, and publishes it
 */

#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>

float x; 

ros::NodeHandle nh;

ROS_CALLBACK(messageCb, std_msgs::Float64, msg)
  x = msg.data - 1.0;
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH-digitalRead(13));   // blink the led
}

std_msgs::Float64 test;
ros::Subscriber s("your_topic", &msg, &messageCb);
ros::Publisher p("my_topic", &test);

void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(p);
  nh.subscribe(s);
}

void loop()
{
  test.data = x;
  p.publish( &test );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(10);
}
```

Here we subscribe to "your_topic", and publish to "my_topic". The publisher publishes at ~100hz, and the value is always the last message received - 1.0.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-07-21**:
Yep, we've tried to make this as easy as possible, while maintaining the feel of roscpp (as much as possible, some limitations on Arduino have forced things like the ROS_CALLBACK macro).

**Comment by [UAV](https://answers.ros.org/users/789/uav/) on 2011-07-20**:
Thanks! This is very helpful! And on another note, apparently we were way over-thinking this...